# ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

Tags: java, maven, pdf, latex, osgi

This problem ties in with the many discussions about the Xerces dependency hell, but I can't seem to solve it.

I'm trying to export LaTeX code to PDF in Java. My code is part of an OSGI bundle for Cytoscape 3.4 and is managed and built with Maven.
The LaTeX library is `jlatexmath` (1.0.6) and to write to SVG and PDF I want to try the apache `fop` (0.95) libs.

Fop is depending on a whole range of `batik` libraries, which in turn depend on `xml-apis` (1.3.04).

With `xml-apis` included, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXFormulaSettingsParser.<init>(TeXFormulaSettingsParser.java:74)
```

Which is understandable as the implementation of `DocumentBuilderFactory` is supposed to be `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl` as included in the JRE.

When I exclude the xml-apis and xml-apis-ext libs, I get another error:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
    <version>0.95</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis-ext</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>


java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.Document not found by... [115]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Which is weird, as `org.w3c.dom.Document` should also just be in the JRE.

So, how can I force Java to use the classes included in Java instead of looking for the ones loaded from the Maven dependencies?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619880/unbelievable-cannot-cast-from-class-x-to-its-super-class/66953887#66953887

Answer (score 1):

Your bundle needs to import the package `org.w3c.dom`. You must import **all packages** that your bundle depends on, with the solitary exception of packages starting with `java.`, e.g. `java.lang`, `java.net` etc.

Comment: My maven-bundle-plugin configuration instructions already state `<Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>`. Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: Indeed explicitly importing this package solved this part of the problem: `<Import-Package>org.w3c.dom,*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>`

Comment: Probably this is because the classes are loaded by reflection, e.g with `Class.forName`. When your code uses a package statically (i.e. compiled into the .class file), bnd can detect that dependency and automatically adds it when you have `Import-Package: *` (which is the default). However bnd cannot detect reflective class loading.

Comment: By the way you should NOT say `Import-Package: *; resolution:=optional`. This makes ALL of the imports of your bundle optional, which is a really bad thing. I will add this comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, thanks to the suggestion of Neil Bartlett that `org.w3c.dom` wasn't imported (although I'm still not sure why an "import *" didn't suffice).

In the configuration instructions of the maven-bundle-plugin, I changed the import to:

```
<Import-Package>org.w3c.dom,*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
```

Also, `xml-apis-ext` should not be excluded, so the `fop` dependency became:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>0.95</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Then, to be complete, the fop artifact seemed to be needing a class from the `avalon-framework-impl`, which was nowhere in the maven dependencies, so I added it separately, while excluding all new attempts to include `xml-apis`:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You should NOT say `Import-Package: *; resolution:=optional`. This makes ALL of the imports of your bundle optional, which is a really bad thing.