# Maven runtime dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 stub jars - say B.jar,C.jar which have XyZ.class in common.The dependency in pom is below:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>pack.y.b</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>pack.y.b</groupId>
            <artifactId>C</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

It is known that dependencies are loaded from pom.xml in the order it is mentioned as in [Maven: Multiple class with the same path implemented in different jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612734/maven-multiple-class-with-the-same-path-implemented-in-different-jar.And) that is indeed how it behaves i.e in local, I get XyZ.class loaded from B.jar right and if B is not available, it is loaded from C.
In contrary, during runtime after deployment, the class is extracted from C instead of B and I ain't sure why it happens and how to rectify. Please clarify and favour.

Comment: How do you deploy? do you use `mvn exec:java`? Or do you build a fat jar (jar-with-dependencies)? Or do you create a custom assembly with the dependencies in a separate directory?

Comment: If at all possible, try to avoid "double classes". The effects are very hard to manage.

Comment: @cello I am in no way related to deployment. I work purely on development. Sorry.

Comment: @JFMeier Yes, i have actually removed that C dependency itself now. But i still don't understand how C gets visited first before B though order is in right way like, the right jar is placed first.

Comment: The POM only defines how the dependencies are loaded at compile time. If packaged into a war/ear, the behaviour can be differen.t

Comment: @Gayathri are both the dependencies (B and C) exported after building war/jar for deployment? did you verify the war/jar file to check this?

Comment: @Gayathri: That the jar files get loaded in the wrong order is to a large part a deployment problem. If you work purely on development, you have to communicate the requirement that B must be on the classpath before C to the deployment persons.

Comment: @Gayathri specifying dependencies in maven pom.xml does not follow any order and does not mean class C will be loaded after class B. If I have say Apache commons 1.x and 2.x as dependencies in pom.xml it does not mean Classloader will load class from 1.x and if not then from 2.x in order. you can provide a <scope> attribute within a dependency to exclude any jar from being say packed.

Comment: @divine Yes,both are exported.

Comment: @Gayathri how did you conclude both B and C got exported?

Comment: @RahulSaini But the order logic actually is right. Coz when i place B first and then C, when i check from which jar that class is taken in local, it is B. If order is reverse, it will be from C .

Comment: @divine I assumed it from its presence in libraries. Please correct me if i sound silly.

Comment: I meant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612734/maven-multiple-class-with-the-same-path-implemented-in-different-jar. in terms of order in pom.xml.

Comment: Please note that i face this issue not in local but in dev. So my question is, if it works well in local, why not in dev?

Comment: @Gayathri Let me understand this clearly. There are 2 different artifacts (B and C) . you have created an object for a class that exists inside (B or C) in your main project (say X). is this understanding correct?

Comment: @Gayathri i understand your problem. let me look into it

Comment: @Gayathri i replicated the setup in my local. deployed the war in tomcat in another machine and verified. it works perfectly for me as expected. did you test the results after deployment properly? are you 100% sure you are facing this issue or is it a misunderstanding of test results? if no, then it is strange.

Comment: Jar C has a.b.c.XyZ class file and B too has a.b.c.XyZ class file. Class named X calls XyZ class,  and B and C being both of same package,  That's where conflict occurs. I tested properly and it is an issue. But the same worked well in local but not after deployment anyway.