# IntelliJ and Maven dependencies - Cannot reorder dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, dependencies

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for a Maven project and i cannot re-arrange the order of the dependencies. Although i change the order in POM.xml and in *appname*.iml files, nothing happens.
I also tried to change the order through the Project Structure menu but it didn't make any change either.

Does anyone know how to fix this or is this a bug of our beloved IDE?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you care? If the dependencies need to be in a specific order, something is really wrong.

Comment: Two of my dependencies have the exact same class so i want to change the order so as to change the final classpath. Also see this:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612734/maven-multiple-class-with-the-same-path-implemented-in-different-jar

Comment: At least one of these dependencies should not be used then. Something is really wrong if two separate dependencies have the same class. I wouldn't trust a dependency doing something nasty like that. What are these dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option because my project depends on those two dependencies. Let's say i have to build a project which combines the functionality of both these apps used as dependencies. Anyway, the problem is how to exactly define the order of the dependencies import...

Comment: @ChrisPi IntelliJ IDEA should use the same order of dependencies as Maven does in the command line.

Comment: I just tried with a maven project generated by Spring Boot Initializr: Reorder dependencies in pom.xml, click on Refresh ("Reimport all maven projects") in the toolbar of the maven toolwindow: => IDEA changed the ordering in project structure accordingly. Which IDEA version are you using?

Comment: @StephenFriedrich your answer combined with File>Invalidate Caches/Restart... did the trick, thanks! IDEA version 2017.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly *not* a bug in IntelliJ.  Perhaps an erroneous assumption in your thinking.

How does order affect anything?

You can see the libraries in alphabetical order (artifact id and group id) in the left view under External Libraries.

Your problem will *not* be solved by ordering.

The right way to solve it is to eliminate version conflicts between your app and Spring.  I would recommend upgrading your application dependencies to match those required by Spring.  I'm assuming that you aren't too far behind and will only require minor code changes, if any.

Comment: As far as i am reading online, the order of the dependencies affects the final classpath. I am facing the following problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612734/maven-multiple-class-with-the-same-path-implemented-in-different-jar and i want to re-arrange the dependencies order as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the bottom of this webpage, and look for "Sort Dependencies". This link explains it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html

I have a project where I include a jar file that contains versions of classes that are missing in a library, but that should come lower down than the library in the sort order so that the library's other classes arent overshadowed. I added the jar file, then use the arrows to move the jar to the desired position. Also, I found that you can highlight the jar file, and use alt + up/down keys, to move the jar file faster than with arrows. I cant find a way to move the jar file instantly to the end of the dependency list, although that would be handy.